# REGEXMATCH for single cell min/max character criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex

I'm very new to the regex scene so forgive my level of intelligence! I want a single cell to be 5 or 7 characters long via data validation and an error message for a false return.

I've come up with this for cell A2:

`=REGEXMATCH(A2&"","^(.){5}$")` --- only 5 characters

`=REGEXMATCH(A2&"","^(.){5,7}$")` ---between 5 and 7 characters

Can't figure out how to do 5 or 7 in a single `REGEXMATCH`.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). It is unclear why you are asking for a regex solution when you apparently only need to check the length of the value. Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `len()`, like this:

`=or( len(A2) = 5, len(A2) = 7) )`

If you additionally need to ensure the value is a number, add `isnumber()`, like this:

`=or( len(A2) = 5, len(A2) = 7) ) * isnumber(A2)`

Only add a `regexmatch()` to the formula if you need to check for the presence  of a certain digit/letter sequence or some such pattern.